# Can I send as someone else using Mail.app on iPad?

Tags: ipad, mail.app, ms-office

Is this possible?

In normal MS Outlook you can send as someone else (if you are on the distribution group I think). It's an option when you reply to an email.

Can you do the same using Mail.app on iPad?

Comment: What Outlook app are you using on your iPad? There is no official Outlook by Microsoft in the App Store.

Comment: @Robuust just the default included mail client - connecting to ms exchange server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail.app on iPad does not support sending as or send on behalf of. So there is no way you can do this via Mail.app.

But you can try this on a Macbook for example:
in Mail > Preferences > Accounts it will show the account you have set up. Next tothe emailaddress, type a comma and then the other email you want to send from. Save it and now when you compose a mail, you can choose which one to send from.

Comment: @Borderline its a valid problem for us, our employees are on various distribution groups and don;t want to cnfuse customers